# Inaccessible value for foreign key in easyadmin listing (Symfony 2.8)

Tags: symfony-2.8, symfony2-easyadmin

I have used easyadmin bundle in my Symfony application. I have user and role entity. I have used role id as an foreign key for user. I am showing user listing in admin section using easy admin.

But for role it show me "Inaccessible" as an value in listing.

If anyone knows how to show actual value for instead of "Inaccessible" then please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The `inaccessible` label is displayed when we cannot access to the value of the given property. We use the PropertyPath Symfony component to get property values. This component tries to get the value using several techniques: via public properties (`role` in your case), via getters (`getRole()`), issers (`isRole()`), etc. Please check that the value of the `role` property can be obtained somehow from outside the entity.

Related to this, and just in case you haven't done it yet, it's a good idea to also define the `__toString()` magic method in the entities used in relations (`Role` entity in this case).

Comment: Thank you Javier for your quick reply. This helps me to resolve it :)

Comment: Thanks ! I had this error because I stupidly pasted the ```class: App\Entity\X```line and I was requesting fields a wrong entity ...

Comment: it helped dudes, just letting you know